# How to add "wrappers" around methods in source code based on a pattern, using sed, awk, grep and friends

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep, indentation

How can I add wrappers to a file based on a pattern?

For instance I have the following:

```
  ...
  find(css_policy_form_stage3).click
  with_ajax_wait
    expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
  end
  with_ajax_wait
    expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
  end
end
it "Stage 3" do
  select(coverage_type, from: css_coverage_type_everquote)
  find(css_has_auto_insurance).click
  ...
```

And I want to 'wrap' those `"with_ajax_wait"` blocks with `it "waits" do ... end` around them.

i.e. I want to get:

```
  ...
  find(css_policy_form_stage3).click
  it "waits" do
    with_ajax_wait
      expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
    end
  end
  it "waits" do
    with_ajax_wait
      expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
    end
  do
end
it "Stage 3" do
  select(coverage_type, from: css_coverage_type_everquote)
  find(css_has_auto_insurance).click
  ...
```

**Notes and Assumptions**:

- block to indent code is always 3 lines long (with... expect... and end).  It would be nice to allow for more than i inner code line but not required for the simplest case.
- the block itself should have an extra 2 space indent.
- there are other end's that are not related (example shown just before "Stage 3"
- it would be nice to be able to specify an inner pattern also, e.g. only these blocks that have `expect` starting the code line being indented.
  I think awk is probably the tool due to the ability to read consecutive lines but I am struggling to know how to write this.

I'm imagining this is a generally useful q&a as adding wrapper within files is not uncommon.

Somewhat similar to my previous question:
[How to use awk to indent a source file based on simple rules?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226201/10043)
However in this case I am adding the wrapper plus the indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way with `sed`:

```
sed -E '/with_ajax_wait/,/end/{       # if line is in this range
H                                     # append to hold space
/end/!d                               # if it doesn't match end, delete it
//{                                   # if it matches
s/.*//                                # empty the pattern space
x                                     # exchange pattern space w. hold space
s/^(\n)( *)/\2it "waits" do\1\2/      # add first line + initial spacing
s/\n/&  /g                            # re-indent all other lines
G                                     # append hold space to pattern space
s/^(( *).*)/\1\2do/                   # add the closing 'do' + initial spacing
}
}
' infile
```

so with an input like:

```
with_ajax_wait
  expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
end
  find(css_policy_form_stage3).click
  with_ajax_wait
    expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
  end
  something here
    with_ajax_wait
      expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
        got some more stuff here to do
          process it
        done
    end
  end
```

the output is:

```
it "waits" do
  with_ajax_wait
    expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
  end
do
  find(css_policy_form_stage3).click
  it "waits" do
    with_ajax_wait
      expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
    end
  do
  something here
    it "waits" do
      with_ajax_wait
        expect(css_coverage_type_everquote).to be_visible
          got some more stuff here to do
            process it
          done
      end
    do
  end
```

It should work with blocks of more than three lines provided your `with_ajax_wait` blocks always ends with `end`.
Replace the closing `do` with `end` if needed as your example is confusing... (you used `end` for the first block and `do` for the second) e.g. this time using `BRE` and `[[:blank:]]` instead of  (space):

```
sed '/with_ajax_wait/,/end/{
/with_ajax_wait/{
G
s/\([[:blank:]]*\)\(with_ajax_wait\)\(\n\)/\1it "waits" do\3  \1\2/
p
d
}
//!{
/end/!{
s/^/  /
}
/end/{
G
s/\([[:blank:]]*\)\(end\)\(\n\)/  \1\2\3\1end/
}
}
}
' infile
```

This one is processing each line in that range separately, the first and the last ones in the range are re-indented and wrappers are added, the rest of the lines are just re-indented.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, with `awk`:

```
awk '/with_ajax_wait/,/end/{          # match the lines between the blocks
  i=substr($0,0,match($0, "[^ ]")-1); # i contains the indented spaces
  if($0~/with_ajax_wait/){            # if it is the starting block
    $0=i"it \"waits\" do\n  "$0       # ... add the starting block before the line
  }else if($0~/end/){                 # if it is the ending block
    $0="  "$0"\n"i"end"               # ... add the end block after the line
  }else{                              # else
    $0="  "$0                         # just indent the line with 2 spaces
  }
}1' file
```

The explanation is in the comments. The `1` at the end of the whole statement is just a true condition, so that `awk` prints all lines.

Comment: Looks good except I am getting extra chrs - `    wit "waits" do
      with_ajax_wait do
        select(auto_model_1, from: css_vehicle1_auto_model)
      end
    eend
    expect(css_vehicle1_auto_submodel option_auto_submodel).to be_present
    wit "waits" do
      with_ajax_wait do
        select(auto_submodel, from: css_vehicle1_auto_submodel)
      end
    eend`

Comment: i.e. wit instead of it and eend instead of end

Comment: @MichaelDurrant can you try it again, I think it was the i variable that contained to much in you case in line 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following SED:

```
sed '/with_ajax_wait/{/end/!N;N;s/^/  it \"waits\" do\n/;s/$/\nend/;s/\n/\n  /g}'
```

This works for the example you gave.

**Mac OS version**

(Tested on OS X 10.8.5) Mac OS doesn't like certain newlines or chaining commands together with semicolons.  Use the following instead:

```
sed -E -e '/with_ajax_wait/{' -e '/end/!N' -e 'N' -e 's/^/  it \"waits\" do\
/' -e 's/$/\
end/' -e 's/\n/\
  /g' -e '}'
```

Those are literal newlines which you can type at the terminal or copy in.

**How it works**

The key is the `N` command.  We want to fill SED's memory (the *pattern space*) with a group of the form

```
  with_ajax_wait
    // commands
  end
```

The program traverses the file a line at a time, until it reaches a line matching `with_ajax_wait`; it then runs the `N` command, which appends more lines to the pattern space, until it reaches a line matching `end`.  The rest of the program is a sequence of substitutions that carry out the wrapping: we append the `it "waits" do` line to the start of the block, the `do` line to the end and then we indent everything.

**Limitations**

- This will not work if the word `end` occurs anywhere *inside* the `with_ajax_wait ... end` block.  Making that work will require more serious parsing of the code itself.  If we can guarantee that the closing `end` will always be indented by two spaces, then we could make this SED a bit better by replacing `{/end/!N` with `{/\n  end/!N` or something.
- The `it "waits" do` and `do` commands are always indented by two spaces, even if the text inside is indented by more or less.  This is probably easier to fix, at the cost of a more complicated command.

Comment: Looks good but I get an error.  I tried command line and I get `$ echo 'ggg' | sed '/with_ajax_wait/{/end/!N;N;s/^/  it \"waits\" do\n/;s/$/\ndo/;s/\n/\n  /g}'
sed: 1: "/with_ajax_wait/{/end/! ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'`

Comment: I'm on osx btw.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I've just added a version that worked for me on Mac OS X.